# Add list of files in a directory to array list

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I am trying to save the list of files in a directory to array list, can you please share the code snippet for Windows PowerShell.

I have 2 files under c:\temp

file1: stack.zip
file2: overflow.zip

Need to store file1 & file2 in a array called

```
$arrlst = ['stack.zip','overflow.zip']
Set-Location -Path "c:\temp"
fileslst = Get-children
$arrlst = [filelist]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running the below will get you what you are after.

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$arrlst = @(
    $(Get-ChildItem -File -Path 'C:\temp' | Select -ExpandProperty Name)
)
```

You need to do `Select -ExpandProperty Name` to ensure that the only result from the `Get-ChildItem` is the filename including extension (`Name`).

Comment: it partially worked, i got the output as single array value, stack.zip overflow.zip as single value, but i can customize.. thank  you Drew

Comment: @VinodhElumalai Sorry about that, I have updated the answer to properly accommodate your request.

Comment: thank you @drew, i tried below one and it worked.               
 $scriptpath='c:\temp'
$fileNames = Get-ChildItem -File -Path $scriptPath -Recurse -Include *.zip | Select -ExpandProperty Name

foreach ($vinodh in $fileNames)
{
write-host $vinodh
$a,$b= $vinodh.split(').')
$b[2].Substring(1)

}

Answer (score -1):

```
$scriptpath='c:\temp'
$fileNames = Get-ChildItem -File -Path $scriptPath -Recurse -Include *.zip | Select -ExpandProperty Name

foreach ($vinodh in $fileNames)
{
write-host $vinodh

}
```

Comment: This doesn't meet your own requirements of creating an array list. This also took 11.230 seconds to run against 5,500 files. My answer will do what you require in 0.450 seconds for 5,500 files. The `Write-Host` command is what is causing the large amount of time in your script and not adding it to an array list.